# Selenium - find element by link text

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am using `selenium webdriver` on Chrome; `python 3` on Windows 10. 
I want to scrape some reports from a database. I search with a company ID and a year, the results are a list of links formatted in a specific way: something like `year_companyID_seeminglyRandomDateAndDoctype.extension`, e.g. `2018_2330_20020713F04.pdf`. I want to get all pdfs of a certain doctype. I can grab all links for a certain doctype using `webdriver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('F04')` or all of that extension with `'.pdf'` instead of `'F04'`, but I cannot figure out a way to check for both at once. First I tried something like

```
links = webdriver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('F04')
for l in links:
    if l.find('.pdf') == -1:
        continue
    else:
        #do some stuff
```

But unfortunately, the links are WebElements:

```
print(links[0])
>> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="78494f3527260607202e68f6d93668fe", element="0.8703868381417961-1")>
print(links[0].get_attribute('href'))
>> javascript:readfile2("F","2330","2015_2330_20160607F04.pdf")
```

so the conditional in the `for` loop above fails.

I see that I could probably access the necessary information in whatever that object is, but I would prefer to do the checks first when getting the links. **Is there any way to check multiple conditions in the `webdriver.find_elements_by_*` methods?**

Comment: Are you sure that `links = webdriver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('F04')` returns you not the list of WebElements, but *javascript objects*? Did you mean `print(links[0].get_attribute('href'))` or `print(links[0].text)`?

Comment: Sorry, I was conflating this with another method I had tried to use before - fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use below code

```
links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in webdriver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('F04') if link.get_attribute('href').endswith('.pdf")')]
```

You can also try XPath as below

```
links = webdriver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(., "F04") and contains(@href, ".pdf")]')
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Quick note that link.get_attribute('href') actually ends with `.pdf");`. Question: Why does `link.get_attribute('href')` return a string? Seems like odd behavior to me.

Answer (score 0):

Andersson's approach seems to work with a slight correction:
if link.get_attribute('href').endswith('.pdf')]  rather than if link.get_attribute('href').endswith('.pdf")')], i.e. delete the ").